# Como posso verificar o lançamento de um Evento com Moq

Tags: c#, moq, .net-5

Estou gerando um teste para a geração de eventos na aplicação e apesar de conferir as assinaturas do Setup e Verify e constatarem que estão iguais, ainda obtenho o erro:

**`Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: s => s.Publish`**

Segue o teste:

```
[Fact]
public async void LivroAdicionadoEventTest()
{
    var mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
    mediatorMock.Setup(s =>
        s.Publish(It.IsAny<LivroAdicionadoEvent>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
        .Verifiable("Notificação não foi lançada.");

    var mediatorHandler = new MediatorHandler(mediatorMock.Object);

    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "TesteDB").Options;
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options, mediatorHandler);
    var repository = new LivroRepository(context);

    var handler = new LivroCommandHandler(repository);

    await handler.Handle(command, CancellationToken.None);

    mediatorMock.Verify(s => 
        s.Publish(It.IsAny<LivroAdicionadoEvent>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), 
        Times.AtLeastOnce(),
        "Erro ao gerar o evento LivroAdicionado.");
}
```

O que mais pode estar fazendo o teste falhar?

**UPDATE**

O código que dispara a publicação é executado no fluxo principal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, no teste não consegue detectar corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E dentro do MediatorHandler, o mediator está mockado corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando:

- Net 5.0.13;
- Moq 4.16.1;
- xUnit 2.4.1;

Comment: coloque o código do método também, além disso o erro é no verify do método Send, nesse pedaço de código nem tem isso, coloque o completo senão fica difícil de ajudar.Mas pra já fez debug? passa mesmo por lá?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu atualizei o código algumas vezes e isso da mensagem Send ficou desatualizado. Bem, o código é executado sim, pelo menos o breakpoint passa corretamente no ponto de Publish. Adicionei a pergunta mais informações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!
O problema da captura era que ao incluirmos o evento na lista de notificações da Entidade, que é do tipo List, o verify não as detectava. Com isso, **passei a verificar o lançamento de eventos do tipo Event** e depois checar o tipo da instância do objeto.

```
public class LivroEventHandlerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async void LivroAdicionadoEventTest()
    {
        var command = LivroRepositoryMock.CriarAdicionarLivroCommand();

        Event ev = null;
        var mediatorMock = new Mock<IMediator>();
        mediatorMock.Setup(s =>
            s.Publish(It.IsAny<Event>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .Callback((Event notification, CancellationToken ct) => { 
                ev = notification;
            })
            .Returns(Task.CompletedTask)
            .Verifiable("O evento não disparado.");

        var repository = LivroRepositoryMock.ObterLivroRepository(mediatorMock); 
        var handler = new LivroCommandHandler(repository);

        await handler.Handle(command, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());

        mediatorMock.Verify(s =>
            s.Publish(It.IsAny<Event>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()),
            Times.AtLeastOnce(),
            "Erro ao gerar o evento LivroAdicionado.");

        ev.Should().BeOfType(typeof(LivroAdicionadoEvent));
    }
}
```

Com isso, verifico se o os comandos criados lançam e disparam os eventos corretos.

Fica aí para quem se interessar em fazer o mesmo.